# How to write a GNUMAKE based testharness

Tags: gnu-make

I am not very good at write make files. But I have a need to write a GNUMAKE based test harness. I did some reserch, but I was not able to find anything useful. So I am not even sure where to begin.

```
TEST_SUITE_DIR:=testSuite

#Get all test names with path  & extention
TEST_SCRIPTS_WITH_PATH:=$(wildcard $(TEST_SUITE_DIR)/*.txt)

#Test name with out path and extention
TEST_SCRIPT_NAME:=$(notdir $(patsubst %.txt,%,$(TEST_SCRIPTS_WITH_PATH)))


vpath %.txt $(TEST_SUITE_DIR)


TEST_LOG_FILE:=$(TEST_SCRIPT_NAME)OutPutFile.txt



#This is the program ./bin/programName being tested
PUT:=man

#Test requrements:
#1) Each test in /testSuite dir should have its own logFile
#2) Each testout will be checked against a goldenout file in /goldenOutput dir to see
#   if the expected resuls match with the test output
#   #3) If the test & golden output file hasnt been modified, we do not want to run that test so
#   we can save time
#   #4) STDERR should be redirected to a stderr.log
#5) During the regression, if a test failed, test name should be written into the regressionReport.log

.PHONY: clean test

test:
        for i in $(TEST_SCRIPTS_WITH_PATH); do \
              echo $$i; \
              $(PUT) `head -n 1 $$i` > $$iOutPutFile.txt; \
        done

#$(foreach i, $(TEST_SCRIPTS_WITH_PATH), $(PUT) `head -n 1 $($i)` > $($i)OutPutFile.txt )
#$(PUT) `head -n 1 $(TEST_SCRIPTS) ` > $(TEST_SCRIPTS)logFile.log


clean:
        rm -f *.d $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o $(PROG)


-include *.d
```

Here is my dataFile.txt(at the moment, I am only trying to get 1 command working),

```
date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A makefile is a way of automating certain tasks, so you can't do anything with Make until you know how how to do it without Make.

There is more than one way to do what you want (a common situation with Make), and you should think about how you want the makefile to scale. The simplest way to construct that command is probably:

```
man `head -n 1 dataFile.txt` > logFile.log
```

So this makefile would suffice:

```
.PHONY: all

all:
    man `head -n 1 dataFile.txt` > logFile.log
```

Many advances on this are possible, but not until we know what you intend to do beyond this.

Comment: It did work for 1 test. How do I use this for more than 1 test? In order for my regression to work the way I want, I had to add few more requirements. Any help would be greatly appreciated. As you can tell, I am a C, C++ programmer. This is like Greek to me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do, why do you need dependencies for the test rule (specially that you made it phony).

Also if you want to test content of file you need to use diff not test